# PHP regex for names

Tags: php, regex

Am Searching about Regex syntax that accept only A-Z a-z till 25 letters only with spaces. Can you help me ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What exactly do you have problems with? It seems to be a rather basic expression, you should find all the information you need on http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Comment: Note that what you describe is not a very good regex to validate names.

Comment: Yeah it is a basic problem. But i know everything related to programming except these one .. !

Comment: Regarding to business requirement it is the desired rule to validate the names ..

Comment: You're going to make Céline O'Brien-Röhm very sad.

Comment: Then it is time to learn about it, which should not be difficult if you know everything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^[a-z ]{0,25}$/i
```

It matches case-insensitive a-z and spaces 0 - 25 times

Comment: so can u explain this for me in more details ?

Comment: Yeah it is not working with me!

Comment: @Hatem Everything is explained.

Comment: Many thanx it is the desired one :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$string = preg_match('/[a-z ]{0,25}/i', $string);
```

This will match a to z and spaces 0 to 25 times.